# wsDualHttpBinding doesn't work for some clients in Intranet

Tags: .net, wcf, intranet, wsdualhttpbinding

I have WCF-service (hosted by IIS) that is used with wsDuallHttpBinding in Intranet environment without Domain controller.

```
 <system.serviceModel>    
    <bindings>

      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicDuplexBinding" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00"
              receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
              hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom"
                 textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" >
          <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
          <readerQuotas ... />
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="..." behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
          binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicDuplexBinding"
          name="Basic" contract="UniDubna.InfSys.Document.WcfDocManager.Contracts.Reporting.IReportService" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10" maxConcurrentInstances="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Some client workstations work perfect with WCF-service, some client workstations can't establish connection (timeout is reached). Meanwhile I can open `http://my-server/my-service.svc` file in every client's browser and can get "wsdl" description. I guess some clients just can't establish 2 ways communication due to firewalls. How can I check that? How can I control callback port for client, preferably in configuration file?

Client configuration looks like:

```
...
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicDuplexBinding" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00"
              receiveTimeout="00:02:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
              hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom"
              textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" >
          <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>

...

<client>
      <endpoint name="myService" bindingConfiguration="BasicDuplexBinding"  address="http://my-server/my-service.svc" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="..."/>
</client>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember `clientBaseAddress="http://IP:PORT/NameService"` in binding in wsdualhttpbinding on client side?